# How to recover the coroutine's true call trace?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

This is a painfully familiar problem to anyone working with async APIs: when your call encounters a failure, the async library's private thread detects it, creates an exception object, and passes it to your callback. The only info worth a dime in that exception is its message and possibly its type. The stack trace is worthless.

Cross-breed that with Google Play's way of reporting the app crashes: the message is stripped and all you get is the stack trace. Now you've got nothing to go with. You just know your app has a bug that you didn't detect in your own testing.

Kotlin's coroutines at least give us some hope that this could be made better. The coroutine stack trace is conceptually there, just difficult to extract. However, currently the stack traces we get are the same, useless ones I described above.

I'm familiar with the [kotlinx-coroutines-debug](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/docs/topics/debugging.md) module and I see there are some provisions on the implementation side to recreate the coroutine stack trace, but how can I make use of these facilities in a production app installed on my user's smartphone?

Answer (score 6):

I faced the same problem. The Kotlin coroutine debug library didn't help me in any way. Therefore, after studying the implementation of coroutines, I wrote my own solution based on bytecode generation and MethodHandle API. It supports JVM 1.8 and Android API 26 or higher. I called it [Stacktrace-decoroutinator](https://github.com/Anamorphosee/stacktrace-decoroutinator).

The reason why the stacktrace is lost is that when the coroutine wakes up, only the last method of its call stack is called.

My library replaces the coroutine awakening implementation. It generates classes at runtime with names that match the entire coroutine call stack.
These classes don't do anything except call each other in the coroutine call stack sequence.

Thus, if the coroutine throws an exception, they mimic the real call stack of the coroutine during the creation of the exception stacktrace.

Comment: Unfortunately made no difference at all in my project. :( All I see at the top of the stack is CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run, no information about what caused it to be scheduled. And I know that it's just a common call to a suspendable function at the top. JetBrains really needs to get on top of this, in .Net async debugging is pretty much hassle free.

Comment: @flodin Could you please provide the stack trace, which generates your app with SD enabled? And didn't you miss the call of function `DecoroutinatorRuntime.load()`. And on what platform is your app, JVM or Android?

Answer (score 5):

First off all the feature is [broken](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/1328) at the moment. If the bug is fixed I would try `System.setProperty(DEBUG_PROPERTY_NAME,DEBUG_PROPERTY_VALUE_ON)`.

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin plugin for IntelliJ IDEA [provides this possibility](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/debug-kotlin-coroutines.html) since [version 1.4](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/whatsnew14.html#coroutine-debugger) (for versions 1.3.8 or later of `kotlinx-coroutines-core`).

Comment: This relates to debugging only, not a stack trace printed to the console when a runtime error happens.

Answer (score 0):

Just found a github issue related to this:

Stacktrace recovery ( https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/pull/792 )
and the related doc (
https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/docs/debugging.md )

Without the caller site stacktrace, coroutine debugging is indeed painful. Hope that the "debug mode" can help. Will try and see.

Answer (score -2):

2023 answer:

- on server, replace Kotlin coroutines with Java 21 virtual threads. Stack trace is full, existing libraries can leverage coroutines out of the box (it's done on jvm level)
- on mobile, do you really need coroutines? Typical mobile app is fine with old threading model. Coroutines bring best benefits when there are thousands of them - this is usually server case

Comment: You _especially_ need coroutines in any frontend app because the GUI is single-threaded.

Comment: You can combine eg `Executor.execute` (to execute something outside main thread), `getMainExecutor().execute` (to write something back to ui thread), `SettableFuture.get` to wait for some data from UI, `SettableFuture.set` to wake up a sleeping thread from ui thread. No coroutines, and the code you pass to `Executor.execute` has always full stack trace.
Coroutines are really, really needed only if you had to create thousands of threads.

Comment: If you want to pursue that line of argument, then coroutines are never needed in a narrow technical sense because they are just a restatement of the async programming style. But if you accept that coroutines are a much nicer way to express async programming logic, and that by "need" we usually mean "highly prefer", then you definitely need coroutines in GUI code.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik But Project Loom allows to use full-featured coroutines, including in GUI applications. Have a look at https://github.com/Anamorphosee/loomoroutines

Comment: It uses java virtual threads which aren't available on Android and probably won't be available anytime soon. Also I don't see need of extra library, virtual threads are already de facto coroutines