# Is there a way to understand what the coroutine was doing when it was cancelled?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, cancellation

Suppose we have a trivial "cancel with timout" case (Kotlin 1.3.50, kotlinx-coroutines-core 1.3.2):

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.runBlocking
import kotlinx.coroutines.delay
import kotlinx.coroutines.withTimeout

suspend fun test() {
    println("test.begin")
    delay(5000)
    println("test.end")
}

fun main() {
    runBlocking {
        withTimeout(100) {
            test()
        }
    }
}
```

I expect that the exception would contain function names like `main` and `test`. The exception should probably contain the coroutine stacktrace.

However, in practice the result is as follows:

```
Exception in thread "main" kotlinx.coroutines.TimeoutCancellationException: Timed out waiting for 100 ms
 at kotlinx.coroutines.TimeoutKt.TimeoutCancellationException (Timeout.kt:126) 
 at kotlinx.coroutines.TimeoutCoroutine.run (Timeout.kt:92) 
 at kotlinx.coroutines.EventLoopImplBase$DelayedRunnableTask.run (EventLoop.common.kt:491) 
 at kotlinx.coroutines.EventLoopImplBase.processNextEvent (EventLoop.common.kt:270) 
 at kotlinx.coroutines.DefaultExecutor.run (DefaultExecutor.kt:68) 
 at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:745)
```

Is there a way to make the cancellation exception to include both "cancellation and the coroutine stack traces"?

Update: `CancellationException` can be detected with `try-catch`, however, I don't want to `try-catch` each and every `suspendable fun` call:

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.*

suspend fun test() {
    println("test.begin")
    try {
        delay(5000)
    } catch (e: TimeoutCancellationException) {
        // It is important to throw an exception different from CancellationException
        throw RuntimeException("delay was cancelled", e) // <-- line 9
    }
    println("test.end")
}

fun main() {
    runBlocking { // <-- line 15
        withTimeout(100) {
            test()
        }
    }
}
```

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: delay was cancelled
 at FileKt.test (File.kt:9) // throw RuntimeException
 at FileKt$test$1.invokeSuspend (File.kt:-1) 
 at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith (ContinuationImpl.kt:33) 
 at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run (Dispatched.kt:334) 
 at kotlinx.coroutines.EventLoopImplBase.processNextEvent (EventLoop.common.kt:270) 
 at kotlinx.coroutines.BlockingCoroutine.joinBlocking (Builders.kt:79) 
 at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking (Builders.kt:54) 
 at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking (:1) 
 at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking$default (Builders.kt:36) 
 at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking$default (:1) 
 at FileKt.main (File.kt:15) // runBlocking
 at FileKt.main (File.kt:-1) 
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: delay was cancelled
 at FileKt.test(File.kt:9) // throw RuntimeException
 at FileKt$test$1.invokeSuspend(File.kt:-1)
 at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
 at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(Dispatched.kt:334)
 at kotlinx.coroutines.EventLoopImplBase.processNextEvent(EventLoop.common.kt:270)
 at kotlinx.coroutines.BlockingCoroutine.joinBlocking(Builders.kt:79)
 at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking(Builders.kt:54)
 at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking(:1)
 at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking$default(Builders.kt:36)
 at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking$default(:1)
 at FileKt.main(File.kt:15) // runBlocking
 at FileKt.main(File.kt:-1)
```

Comment: Seems related to [a question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54349418/how-to-recover-the-coroutines-true-call-trace). Maybe the debug feature helps you, it didn't fit my use case.

Comment: What about the 'try {...} catch (e: TimeoutCancellationException) {...}' ? Doesn't solve your problem ?

Comment: i meant : does the exception contains more information ? (not shown in the stacktrace)

Comment: A pity the stacktrace as also the exception doesn't really give any helpful information...  Playing around with `select` and `onTimeout` I was able to get both stack traces with the appropriate "coroutine boundary"... however I then wrote a lot of boilerplate-code and I had to put a `try`/`catch` around the `test()`-call itself, just to get them... not really what one wants...

Comment: I can add try-catch, I can catch `e: TimeoutCancellationException` and wrap it with my own `RuntimeException("here", e)`, however, I don't really want to wrap each and every suspendable call with try-catch.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik, I tried adding `-ea -Dkotlinx.coroutines.stacktrace.recovery=true -Dkotlinx.coroutines.debug=on`, and it did not improve the stack trace.

Comment: Due to this problem I have a long-standing bug in my Android app that I have no clue where it's coming from. All the crash report gives me is the boilerplate `Task` completion code path on the Google API side.